# Trigger a javascript function when button is clicked and stop when clicked again

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

So I wish to add an effect to my website of floating particles. Came across this codepen which does the exact thing - https://codepen.io/OliverKrieger/pen/EjLEVX.

I've been trying to change it a bit so that the particles only trigger when a checkbox is checked. I understand it might've been already answered on SO but in the codepen code, there is an window.onload function which automatically fires it when window is loaded. I want there to be a checkbox instead.

I tried putting the following in html -

```
<input  type="checkbox" id="switch" onchange="function()"">
        <label for="switch" >Toggle</label>
```

But it seems like the script still triggers automatically. Can someone help me with this please? I'm new to programming so I apologize for any vagueness. Please lemme know if I can provide more details. Any input would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `function` is a keyword and not a function name. The function is still run as soon as the page loads because of the way it is defined in the javascript, and your HTML addition has no effect on this.

You need to change your function into a named function, declared using the function keyword:

```js
function functionName() { ... }
```

And then you can call it by its name in your HTML:

```html
<input  type="checkbox" id="switch" onchange="functionName()">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried naming the function and then using the onchange trigger but it doesn't seem to work. At what exact places in the script should I change the function name for the onchange trigger to work? I apologize for vagueness as I'm new to programing and don't have much experience.

Comment: Do you think maybe the 'window.onload' is interfering with it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
(function() {
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

$(window).resize(function() {
  ParticleCanvas.width = ($(window).width() - 20);
  ParticleCanvas.height = ($(window).height() - 10);
});

$(function() {
  let request = null;

  $("#switch").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      animateDust();
    } else {
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(request);
    }

  })

  var ParticleCanvas = document.getElementById("ParticleCanvas");
  var context = ParticleCanvas.getContext("2d");
  ParticleCanvas.width = ($(window).width() - 20);
  ParticleCanvas.height = ($(window).height() - 10);

  $("switch").click(function() {
    animateDust();
  })

  // All the info stored into an array for the particles
  var particles = {},
    particleIndex = 0,
    settings = {
      density: 20,
      particleSize: 2,
      startingX: ParticleCanvas.width / 2,
      startingY: ParticleCanvas.height,
      gravity: -0.01
    };

  // Set up a function to create multiple particles
  function Particle() {
    // Establish starting positions and velocities from the settings array, the math random introduces the particles being pointed out from a random x coordinate
    this.x = settings.startingX * (Math.random() * 10);
    this.y = settings.startingY;

    // Determine original X-axis speed based on setting limitation
    this.vx = (Math.random() * 2 / 3) - (Math.random() * 3 / 3);
    this.vy = -(Math.random() * 5 / 3);

    // Add new particle to the index
    // Object used as it's simpler to manage that an array
    particleIndex++;
    particles[particleIndex] = this;
    this.id = particleIndex;
    this.life = 0;
    this.maxLife = 200;
    this.alpha = 1;
    this.red = 0;
    this.green = 255;
    this.blue = 255;
  }

  // Some prototype methods for the particle's "draw" function
  Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;

    // Adjust for gravity
    this.vy += settings.gravity;



    // Age the particle
    this.life++;

    this.red += 2;

    this.alpha -= 0.005;


    // If Particle is old, it goes in the chamber for renewal
    if (this.life >= this.maxLife) {
      delete particles[this.id];
    }



    // Create the shapes
    context.clearRect(settings.leftWall, settings.groundLevel, ParticleCanvas.width, ParticleCanvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + this.red + ", " + this.green + ", " + this.blue + ", " + this.alpha + ")";
    // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the ParticleCanvas
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, settings.particleSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();

  }

  function animateDust() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, ParticleCanvas.width, ParticleCanvas.height);

    // Draw the particles
    for (var i = 0; i < settings.density; i++) {
      if (Math.random() > 0.97) {
        // Introducing a random chance of creating a particle
        // corresponding to an chance of 1 per second,
        // per "density" value
        new Particle();
      }
    }

    for (var i in particles) {
      particles[i].draw();
    }
    request = window.requestAnimationFrame(animateDust);
  }


})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #555555;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#ParticleCanvas {
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

#container {
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ParticleCanvas"></canvas>
<div id="container">
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch">
  </form>
  <label for="switch">Toggle</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like charm, sir. Thanks. I have one more question. When we uncheck the box, it does stop the floating particles but they are still on the screen. Is there any way to completely make them disappear? Like kind of resetting it? Even the above solution works though.